# How can I disable animation just for first render

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have fully working code and I am okay with my approach, the only issue that I am facing is having animation at app lunch, my approach force my view to animate on onAppear, which is okay, but I want my view appear with no animation when my App lunch for first time, then the code should work as coded. How can I make my view put a deference on very first onAppear and the other onAppear that happens because of Button. Looking for solving the issue in my question in simplest and easiest way possible.

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showView: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if (showView) { MyView() }
        
        Button("toggle") { showView.toggle() }
        
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State private var start: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: start ? 300.0 : 100.0, height: start ? 300.0 : 100.0)
            .onAppear(perform: { start.toggle() })
            .animation(.default, value: start)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
.animation(.default, value: start)
```

wrap wherever you change `start` and want it animated with:

```
withAnimation(.default) {
    start.toggle()
}
```

Comment: No, Animation should be use animation modifier as I mentioned in my code inside MyView. I did not use withAnimation in my approach as well,  also I asked for disabling animation on very first render. Ps: Your answer completely ignores my approach and try to change the question.

Comment: You can't with `.animation` you have to make it conditional using a `withAnimation` block. Are you saying you want the animation ANY time the view appears, except the first?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned.

Comment: Well, then you have to use `withAnimation`.